# c, array and malloc difference. error

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

i am dev in AES. so i download and use.
so, here is my question.
if i use [array] are good work. but if i use [malloc] are error. what am i wrong?

```
uint8_t key[] = { 0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c };
uint8_t iv[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
uint8_t *original = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa65aaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssss65sssaaaaaa";
int len = 65;
uint8_t out[64] = {0,}; 

uint8_t ctext[200] = { 0, };
//uint8_t *ctext = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * len);

for (int i = 0; len > 0; i+=64) {
    len = len - 64;     
    AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(out, original + i, 64, key, iv);
    memcpy(ctext+i , out, 64);
}
uint8_t ptext[200] = { 0, };
len = 65;
for (int i = 0; len > 0; i += 64) {
    len = len - 64;  
    AES_CBC_dec(out, ctext + (i * sizeof(uint8_t)), key, iv, 64);
    memcpy(ptext + (i * sizeof(uint8_t)), out, 64);
}
return 0;
```

ctext[200]

it's works. but. if i'll use

*ctext

are error

what am i wrong?
it's c lang.

Comment: While using artray, you use `200`, why mallocing for only `len`?

Comment: The second time through your loop, you want to `memcpy` to the 64 bytes at `ctext + 64` and you have not allocated accordingly. Such errors are best found with the help of a debugger or a memory chacker such as Valgrind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `len = 65` you `memcpy` twice as `len = len - 64` is still `> 0` after the first iteration.
Your `memcpy`  is now starting at ctext + 64 which will go out of bounds for the memory allocation of `sizeof(uint8_t) * len`

You can see this by using `len = 64` resulting in only one iteration of the loop or by keeping `len = 65` and doubling the memory allocation `sizeof(uint8_t) * len * 2`

If you use `malloc` don't forget to free the memory afterwards

Answer (score 0):

*ctext is the first uint_8 from the array. Use ctext instead (the address). Be sure to alloc enough space.